# Htaccess redirect to https while having another condition from vue-router

Tags: .htaccess, vue-router

I would like to merge both of these server configurations:

1) [Vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) (to display paths correctly)

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

2) I would also like to redirect user to use `https://`, I found solution online:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

How do I connect both of these so I can use them in my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rules :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  #enforce https
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  #rewrite non-existent uris to /index.html
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Change `R` to `R=301` in the http to https rule if you want to make the redirection permanent (browser and search engine cached) .

Comment: The `L` flag i the redirection rule is not required, an external redirection terminates the rewriting process immediately for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Arkascha You are right  L has no effect when used with R. But its actually a good habit to always use L at the end of each rules (especially  for beginners) as its easier to understand the RewriteRule line with L and proper syntax.

Comment: Ahem... a strange advice, but anyway: _if_ you want to give that advice, then I would suggest to use the `END` flag instead of the `L` flag which is well known to _not_ do what beginners usually expect...

Comment: @Arkascha   `END` and `L` are two different flags and used for different purposes. Using `END` in external redirection rules is useless as its designed to terminate internal rewrite processing only. And not all apache versions support it so suggesting a beginner to use END can point him/her in a wrong direction IMO.

Comment: We disagree, but that is perfectly fine :-)